# What happens if I try to define a pointer which points to a string literal in C?

Tags: c, string, pointers, memory, string-literals

For example,

```
char * first = "Hello World!";
```

My questions is,

1. Is the string literal stored in memory? (If it is I guess the pointer `first` is the address of inital element of the string literal "`Hello World`")
2. If not, then is some kind of random pointer value stored in `first`?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Moot, since the first answer is "yes".

Comment: What do you mean by `saving a pointer`?

Comment: @RawN I think the word "define" is more suitable !

Comment: @RawN I think he means store the pointer in `first`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, string literals are stored in memory. The C and C++ standards just say that string literals have static storage duration, any attempt at modifying them gives undefined behavior, and multiple string literals with the same contents may or may not share the same storage.

Answer (score 3):

Yes the string literal is stored in memory, usually it's stored in the **.rodata** section

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your platform and it is *implementation-defined*. In general it goes to the **read-only memory**, if available on your system. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589949/c-string-literals-where-do-they-go).